# Why does my object method not register? Javascript

Tags: javascript

here is the code for my project: 
'_' is a selector method. 
'update' is run on an interval of 0.1 
'init' creates the 
'Ball' is the object I'm trying to create 
'ball.set()' is the method that is not working.

```
var width = window.innerWidth/3;
var height = window.innerHeight-60;
var balls = [];
var id;

function rand(min, max) {
    return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function run(){
    init();
}

function init(){
    document.write("<div style='width:"+width+"px;height:"+height+"px;' id='container'></div>");
    new Ball(width/2-12.5, height/2-12.5, rand(-2, 2), rand(-2, 2), 1);
    id = setInterval(update, 0.1);
}

function _(elem){
    return document.getElementById(elem);
}

function update(){
    for(var b in balls){
        b.set();
    }
}

function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, ind){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.ind = ind;
    balls[this.ind] = this;
    _("container").innerHTML+=("<div style='top:"+y+"px;left:"+x+"px;' class='ball' id='ball"+this.ind+"'></div>");
    this.deleteBall = function () {
        _('ball'+this.ind).outerHTML = "";
        balls[this.ind] = null;
    };

    this.set = function(){
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        var elem = _("ball"+this.ind);
        elem.style.left = this.x + 'px';
        elem.style.top = this.y + 'px';
    };
}

run();
```

I'm trying to make a Ball object for a JS game I'm making. The only problem is Google Chrome is giving me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.set is not a function
at update (ballgame.js:29)
update @ ballgame.js:29
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show all the code...

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the complete requirement, but I found the cause for this issue.The problem is with the line

```
balls[this.ind] = this;
```

Assume for the first time the constructor is called with 'ind' value of 5. This will set balls[5]=this object. Now 'balls' array length becomes 6 and  balls[0] through balls[4] will contain value as 'undefined'.

Now in 'update' method, when you iterate through balls array, as balls[0] through balls[4] are undefined, you get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.set is not a function
```

Comment: no errors in the other methods. I updated the code to include everything the project had.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the exact root cause. Hope this helps to resolve the error in your logic and refactor the code as per your requirement.

Comment: how would I add objects to the balls array otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure what significance does the parameter 'ind' has in your application. If you don't have to push the balls object in that specific index of array then you can use `balls.push(this)`